# An oxymoronic mystery

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> I am your wildest dreams, your deepest secrets.
>   I am your follower, your guide.
>   I am who you say I am not; I am your world.

To what does this riddle refer?

Answer (score 3):

It may be:

> Your subconscious

Reasoning:
I am your wildest dreams, your deepest secrets.

> Your dreams come from your subconscious. And your deepest secrets you sometimes push down out of conscious memory.

I am your follower, your guide.

> Your subconscious follows where you go (it has to), but sometimes it guides you to decisions that you don't necessarily know why you made them.

I am who you say I am not; I am your world.

> Your subconscious is you, but sometimes you deny that it is since you don't control the impulses that come out of it. It is also your world, as it is compiled from everything that's happened to you.

Answer (score 3):

I am

> Your Past

I am your wildest dreams, deepest secrets

> In most of our wildest dreams, we might dream about past. Our past is our deepest secrets.

I am your follower, your guide.

> Our past follows us and guides us

I am who you say I am not: I am your world

> We say we are not our past.